How to request a cross-origin file that contains relative URLs?
I have a situation where I have two servers, Server A and Server B. (Both are running on localhost on different ports.)
Server A:
a/
  index.html
  index.js

Server B:
b/
  library.js
  font.ttf

Server B hosts an library.js and font.ttf. To load this font file, the library.js file has a fetch call with a relative path, like so:
fetch('./font.tff')

When loaded from it's own origin, the Server B setup works fine.
However, when loaded a cross-origin request from Server A (with a/index.js importing b/library.js), Server B's code fails because now that relative './font.ttf' path is relative to Server A instead (on a different port), which has no such file.
Is there a way to continue to use relative paths on Server B, while having code be isolated so that it can be requested from a different origin and still work?

(The nuances of why I have two servers running has to do with Electron, and how Server A is the renderer process itself, and Server B is my own extra server with a dynamic set of files that might get loaded.)

Can you add a check whether the file exists on server A and if doesn't exist, proxy the request to server B? In this setup, you can't have two files with the same name.
